# How can I connect to the internet by sim card?

Tags: ipad, network, cellular-data

I have a **ipad mini 2** and I can connect to the internet via WiFi as well. My ipad is *cellular* model and I've putted a sim card in it. But when I turn off the wifi, the internet will be die and I cannot open a web page. Here is my screen shots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Ok well as you see, my sim card supports `3G` technology but sadly I cannot use the internet via the sim card's internet connection. What's wrong and how can I create a internet connection based on the sim card?

Comment: Is the SIM card activated by a cellular provider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you should do is make sure that your model iPad supports the cellular network you're trying to connect to.

In America, we have two major cellular networks, [GSM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSM) and CDMA. I suspect that this is the heart of your issue.

Apple's [support website](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201471) has a webpage that helps identify your model so you can continue troubleshooting.

If push comes to shove, you'll need to either call your cell provider or go into one of their stores to have them resolve the issue by either giving you a new SIM or reactivating the device on their network.